# Best way to select from database and using special characters

Tags: php, mysql, seo

I would like to put the following question in front of you.

The database consists of various names. These names can contain 'special' characters like é, ê & alike.

My plan was to have a SEO friendly URL containing the names from the database. The creation of the link is not a big issue, just replace all the special characters with their normal characters using the normalize function or a str_replace function.

But then when I want to query the database using the SEO friend URL (after the necessary validations and checks). The DB ofcourse doesn't return any results due to the special characters.

Now comes the question, is there a way to query the database without the special characters or would it be better to have a separate column in the database where I store the name without the special characters (less need to clean them during the creation of the link and easy to query on). This will have the need to maintain two columns, but will allow me to easily query the database.

Any idea's?

Comment: Do everything in utf-8. No need for special handling.

Comment: Why doesn't the Db return results with the special characters? If you're using the appropriate character sets, they should be queryable like any others (with the caveat of some special characters being particularly case sensitive (Straße/Strasse))

Comment: Please note that the DB contains names with special characters "hôtel" is in the database: "h&ocirc;tel". When I query it, I use the query string 'hotel'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the collation `hôtel` will be equal to `hotel`:

```
mysql> select 'hôtel' = 'hotel';
+--------------------+
| 'hôtel' = 'hotel'  |
+--------------------+
|                  1 |
+--------------------+
```

The problem you have is that you are storing html entities (`h&ocirc;tel`) which I think is very wrong because you are mixing a presentation issue with a persistence issue. Get rid of it and choose an adequate collation to your charset then make it the database default or [set it for each query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html).

An adequate charset for web use would be `utf8`. To [set the database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-database.html) up do:

```
create database mydatabase character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: could you give a suggestion how to setup the database? Your suggestion is to have no html entities in the database, but just the actual characters? Any good suggestion/resources where I can find more information on this?

Comment: @Ralf Edited the answer to include the `create database` statement. Yes I mean you store the actual character in instead of the html entities.

Comment: in a small test it works perfect. Seems to be the best option. I will need to alter my table, but it will have a great effect on the production of the website.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to put an ID in the URL like URL's from Stackflow.

Comment: that was my fallback, but I don't really like it from an visual point.

Comment: You could make a huge replace statement in your query.
This is one time a huge amount of work and time:

WHERE REPLACE(`fieldname`, '&ocirc;', 'o') = '{$sURL}'